# Open url from Today Extension

Tags: ios, swift, today-extension

I'm trying to open a deep link from my today extension widget to my main app with no luck.

```
    //ExtensionViewController.swift
public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let url = URL(string: "ACTION_TODAY://")
    self.extensionContext?.open(url!, completionHandler: { (completed) in
    })
}
```

Info.plist of the main app : (I guess `ACTION_TODAY://` is not needed, but `ACTION_TODAY` alone gives me the same result)
[image]

```
    //AppDelegate.swift
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL,
                 sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {

    let action_today = "ACTION_TODAY://"
    if url.absoluteString.contains(action_today) {
        return true
    }

    return false
}

func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {

    let action_today = "ACTION_TODAY://"
    if url.absoluteString.contains(action_today) {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

When I select one of the item of the collectionView displayed in the today extension, the console gives me a `__55-[_NCWidgetExtensionContext openURL:completionHandler:]_block_invoke failed: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-50 "(null)"`

Comment: And for some reasons, it was a really bad idea to include an underscore in the URL Scheme... Removing it has fixed the issue. The widget can now correctly open the container app.

Comment: great, and space is also not allowed there.. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

- In today view controller, put the following code where you need to open the main iOS app from the extension.

  ```
  let appURL = NSURL(string: "StarterApplication://")

  self.extensionContext?.open(appURL! as URL, completionHandler:nil)
  ```

Comment: like I said, the issue was only the presence of an underscore in my url value.

Comment: How is the name of StarterApplication determined?

Comment: @JoeFratianni it's determined by URL scheme in your app Info.plist